# What type is passed to functions from `onClick`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have some javascript that looks like this:

```js
const menu = (
        <Menu onClick={handleMenuClick}>
            {menuItems.map((item) => (
                <Menu.Item key={item.key} icon={item.icon} style={styles.item}>
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>{item.value}</span>
                </Menu.Item>
            ))}
        </Menu>
    )
```

With the key piece being the `handleMenuClick`

That function is defined as:

```js
    const handleMenuClick = (event) => {
        console.log(event.key)
        console.log(typeof (event.key))
    }
```

However, I'm not sure what type the `event` is, and how it's getting the `key` value?

Additionally, when I try this in typescript, it looks like its a [Synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). However, I try to access the `key` value with `e.target.value` and I keep getting errors.

So I'm not sure what I'm not understanding

Comment: Write the function inline to see the type, then copy that type when defining a standalone function. This technique works for all situations when you don't know the proper typing of a callback.

Comment: It's `e: any` in JS and `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)` in TS... I see... It looks like they are different in TS and in JS...

Comment: No, write it inline at first, not as a standalone function, so you can see what the type of the parameters is inferred to be. (It's a `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>`, but knowing the general approach is even better)

Comment: OH. THAT IS HELPFUL. `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>` So that's how I can see... It's weird that it's different...

Comment: Why does it change all the time?

Comment: Different from what? What does what change? `JS` doesn't have types at all, so saying it's different from JS doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a TS function that takes a callback, and you want to define the callback elsewhere but aren't sure of the right typing to use, first write the function inline with the callback, and use an IDE that can tell you the types of variables. Then look at the type of the variable:

[image]

Then copy that type when defining a standalone callback that you can pass in.

This works not only for `onClick` in React, but for any situation where you're dealing with a callback you don't know the proper type for.